# Use StrStr in Uninstaller Code

Tags: installation, nsis

Is it possible to use the NSIS function `StrStr` in uninstaller macro functions? Ie, call the function `un.StrStr` if it exists?

I am having trouble remembering if StrStr is part of the main API like `IntCmp` and `FileExists` or if its a function someone has written and widely distrubuted? If its the latter than I'll search through my nsi files and edit the code to work for uninstaller code aswell.

How do other people use StrStr in uninstaller code?

Answer (score 0):

The native string instructions are `StrCpy`, `StrLen` and `StrCmp`.

StrStr is located in [StrFunc.nsh](http://nsis.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nsis/NSIS/trunk/Include/StrFunc.nsh?view=markup), use `${StrStr}` and `${UnStrStr}` in your code. See the [StrFunc readme](http://nsis.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nsis/NSIS/trunk/Include/StrFunc.txt?view=markup) for more information...

Comment: why the down vote? PS the code is not mine but a snippet someone has generously made public: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Get_command_line_parameter_by_name

Comment: That code is several years old, most helper functions are wrapped in macros these days to avoid the uninstaller issue.